# Use result from case statement in another case statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I have a view which contains a cast statement for one column. This cast statement contains a case statement. This statement works. The result of this statement is 1, 2, or 3.

From here, I need to use the result from the previous case statement (I used a WITH statement and it doesn't work) to determine the value of the column. A simple case statement that assigns yes, no or null to the above statement's value (1,2, or 3)

ANY help is appreciated. Thank you.

Example using pseudo-code:

```
CAST (
   WITH case_output 
   AS(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS
                    (select from table where blah blah)
                THEN 
                    (select column from that table)
            ELSE
                 (select from some another table)
        END 
       )     
  CASE
        WHEN case_output = 1
            THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN case_output = 2
            THEN 'No'
    else 
        NULL
 AS VARCHAR2 (10))
    column_name,
    .... [rest of query]
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Is `case_output` a CTE or a column?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour with a working example using `select from dual` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the query name and the column name of the `WITH` clause. For example, it's

```
WITH my_query AS (SELECT c1 AS my_column FROM t1)
SELECT my_column FROM my_query;
```

Secondly, you'll always need a `FROM` clause in Oracle's SQL. Use the dummy table `DUAL` as stand-in:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN END AS my_column
  FROM DUAL;
```

Minimal working example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (c2 INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2);

WITH case_query AS (
   SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1=100) 
               THEN (SELECT c1 FROM t1)
               ELSE (SELECT c2 FROM t2)
           END AS case_output 
     FROM dual)
SELECT CASE case_output
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'No'
       ELSE NULL
        END second_case_output
  FROM case_query;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I didn't know how to use the WITH clause but now it's much clearer :)